# React-native how to set animation for state-changing height

Tags: react-native

I have a view like this:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', height: this.state.height}}>
                    <Swiper 
                    onIndexChanged={(index) => {
                        if(index == 0) {
                            this.setState({height: 100})
                        } else  if(index == 1) {
                            this.setState({height: 190})
                        } else if(index == 2) {
                            this.setState({height: 170})
                        } else if(index == 3) {
                            this.setState({height: 250})
                        }
                    }}
...Content
```

and as you can see, I am updating height by some conditions and its working pretty fine.

What im looking for is, how can I make this resizing animated (not a fancy one, a basic one would enough).

Actually i exactly need a wrapper like [this](https://muffinman.io/react-animate-height/) but its for reactjs.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Animated API (https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated).

Configure animation

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      myanim: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
}
```

Start animation in your if blocks for example.

```
Animated.timing(this.state.myanim, {
            toValue: 190,
            duration: 500,
          }).start()
```

On your render

```
<Animated.View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent', height: this.state.myanim}}>
                    <Swiper 
                    onIndexChanged={(index) => {
                        if(index == 0) {
                            this.setState({height: 100})
                        } else  if(index == 1) {
                            this.setState({height: 190})
                        } else if(index == 2) {
                            this.setState({height: 170})
                        } else if(index == 3) {
                            this.setState({height: 250})
                        }
                    }}
...Content
```

This is the idea and it should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for help. I am receiving json value of type nsstring cannot be converted to a ygvalue error with this code. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change View to Animated.View . Its all working now! Thanks for your assist..